# Hive - change column types for all columns without knowing column names

Tags: hadoop, hive, casting, hiveql

Given table of format:

```
hive> describe tableA;
OK
id      int
ts      timestamp
var     float
...     ...
```

I would like to utilise a solution similar to [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17497699/1655567) discussed by [@interskh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633289/interskh) *converting **all** columns to strings without knowing and explicitly referring to column names.*

On the lines of the syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA CHANGE <<all columnns>> string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to change the column's datatype one by one. You can't alter all the column's name or datatype in a single query, according to the official documentation. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613590/alter-hive-multiple-column) question I recently answered.